# Rails5- Why gem is using different ruby version in development and in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using a addon which uses rest api. It works in development environment and works partially in production.

I gave an invalid url to it and found they have different ruby versions.

The rest-client is using ruby-2.3.1 in development and using 2.3.0 in production.

```
irb(main):007:0> @firstfeature = ButterCMS::Post.find("how-caish-speaills1")
RestClient::ResourceNotFound: 404 Resource Not Found: {"detail":"Not found."}
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:74:in `return!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:495:in `process_result'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:421:in `block in transmit'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:413:in `transmit'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:176:in `execute'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:41:in `execute'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:111:in `follow_redirection'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:67:in `return!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:495:in `process_result'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:421:in `block in transmit'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:413:in `transmit'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:176:in `execute'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:41:in `execute'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/buttercms-ruby-1.0.6/lib/buttercms-ruby.rb:32:in `request'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/buttercms-ruby-1.0.6/lib/buttercms/butter_resource.rb:38:in `find'
        from (irb):7
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
irb(main):008:0>
```

This is rails console from heroku development environment.

```
>> @firstfeature = ButterCMS::Post.find("how-caish-speaills1")
RestClient::ResourceNotFound: 404 Resource Not Found: {"detail":"Not found."}
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:74:in `return!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:495:in `process_result'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:421:in `block in transmit'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:413:in `transmit'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:176:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:41:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:111:in `follow_redirection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:67:in `return!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:495:in `process_result'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:421:in `block in transmit'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:413:in `transmit'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:176:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:41:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/buttercms-ruby-1.0.6/lib/buttercms-ruby.rb:32:in `request'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/buttercms-ruby-1.0.6/lib/buttercms/butter_resource.rb:38:in `find'
        from (irb):2
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
>>
```

This is the Gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby   '2.3.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0.rc1'
```

Can someone help in resolving this? Thanks

Comment: You installled different version of ruby on production. So what do you expect?

Comment: @emrahbasman How do I change it in Heroku?

Comment: Maybe this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791881/heroku-ruby-version-wont-upgrade

Comment: Update the bundler version, what is the current version that you are using?